# How is this circuit a voltage regulator?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I understand how the v_o expression is found, but I don't really understand how or why it's a voltage regulator.

[image]

Comment: Because you have a load-independent expression for \$V_O\$ as opposed to \$I_O\$ ;). Assuming reasonable loads, of course.

Comment: Why is there a variable resistor on the output of your opamp?

Answer (score 2):

The circuit is a voltage regulator because the output voltage \$V_o\$ does not depend on the load. Whether you connect a \$1~\Omega\$, \$1~\text{k}\Omega\$, \$10~\text{k}\Omega\$, etc., resistor from the output to GND, the voltage at \$V_o\$ will remain at the voltage set by the expression you've derived. The current \$I_o\$, however, will be different in all these cases. In other words, it *regulates* the voltage \$V_o\$ based on the values of \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and \$V_Z\$.

The "opposite" circuit is a current regulator, which keeps the current \$I_o\$ at some value regardless of the load connected to it (and the voltage \$V_o\$ changes accordingly to make this happen).

Comment: Vz remains constant as well, irrespective of power supply variations.

Comment: @MituRaj Of course. \$V_Z\$ depends on the chosen diode, just like \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ depend on the chosen resistors.

Comment: what's the purpose of using a BJT?

Comment: @David It's used as a current buffer: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-buffer-an-op-amp-output-for-higher-current-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Because the zener diode on the left provides a voltage reference, and the op-amp + transistor provides a power, 1-quadrant amplifier for that voltage reference.

Answer (score 0):

The Zener diode provides the regulation source. Ideally, you would choose a Zener whose temperature coefficient is near zero (around 5V -to- 6V). Two feedback resistors allow you to choose an output voltage (regulated) that is greater than or equal to the Zener voltage.

Just like most **voltage regulator** chips, this circuit sources current, but cannot sink current. It has no "input", so it cannot really be called an **amplifier**. If you regard \$V_A\$ as an *input*, then the output voltage is independent of its input (so long as *input > output*).